# xml doesn't work in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I use this code in flash

```
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("xml/vragen.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
function processXML(e:Event):void {
myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
trace(myXML.firstChild.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue);
}
```

but I get errors:

TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

```
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

what can I do?

Comment: What is the content of your XML? Are you sure that XML is valid? Try to trace `e.target.data` before creating the XML to check the validity.

Comment: #taskinoor I have the code from here http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xml/ I just want the text out of the XML file to show up before I used this code var myXML:XML = new XML();
myXML.ignoreWhite=true;
myXML.onLoad = function(sucess) {
if(sucess) {
subjectTXT = this.firstChild.childNodes[0].childNodes­[2].firstChild.nodeValue;

subjectBox.text = subjectTXT;
}
}
myXML.load("xml/tutex.xml"); but thst didn't worked

Comment: @user2852398, you got my question wrong. I asked what is the content of `xml/vragen.xml` file? Does that file contain valid XML data? If not then you may get error 1010 while trying to create XML object from it.

Comment: @taskinoor <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vragen>
 <flap1>
    <vraag1>blabla</vraag1>
    <vraag2>blabla</vraag2>
 </flap1> 
</vragen> this is the structure of my xml file

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the content of your XML, remove

```
trace(myXML.firstChild.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue);
```

which corresponds to a specific structure and may be project-dependant. The nodes may not exist in your case so trying to access `firstChild` and `nodeValue` will cause an error.
Instead, you can write simply

```
trace(myXML.toXMLString());
```

Comment: I hardly believe that this explains the cause of error #1010.

Comment: Both firstChild and nodeValue may not exist.

Comment: if `firstChild` is not there then it should be error #1009(i.e. trying to access something of null), shouldn't it? I suspect that the XML content is invalid, i.e. OP is getting the error in first line. Let's see what OP says about it.

Comment: I apologize for the downvote. I was wrong. This is indeed the problem and correct answer. However, I can't revoke my downvote unless you edit the answer. So, please edit the answer by simply adding the cause of error so that I can revoke my downvote and give an upvote instead.